# Cannot install Debian when CSM is disabled

Tags: debian, uefi

I am trying to install Debian 11.2.0 (debian-11.2.0-amd64-netinst.iso) on an old Lenovo ThinkCentre M92p (Intel Core i5-3470).

I upgraded BIOS to latest version (9SKT9CA, released on December 24th 2018) and disabled CSM.

Installer works fine until following two errors are thrown.

> Failed to create a file system

When I select continue…

> This machine's firmware has started in UEFI mode but it looks like there may be an existing operating system already installed using "BIOS compatibility mode".

I am installing Debian on an empty exFAT-formatted Samsung T7 Touch SSD… no other operating system is present besides live installer.

What am I missing? Thanks for helping out!

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

[image: Startup config]

Comment: You could try "zapping" your SSD, i.e. removing all partitioning (assuming there is no data you still need!). Perhaps then the false detection of a possible CSM OS is removed. You cannot use exFAT for Linux, anyway.

Comment: ...  in fact perhaps "forcing UEFI mode" will help you move ahead in the installer and do just that. If you do please make a simple installation first - don't spend much time now selecting packages in case it does not work.

Comment: Thanks for helping out @Ned64. I tried forcing UEFI mode and that keeps looping back to partitioning step. Puzzled…

Comment: If there are no data: Please try "zapping" the disk. I will write this in an answer because a comment is too short.

Comment: I just zapped disk using GParted (deleted all partitions) and same issue is present… was there anything else I needed to do in GParted?

Comment: I have never used `parted` but I assume it does the right thing? Perhaps try the `dd`, too. then report back?

Comment: Thanks for answer, on it!

Comment: Just to be sure: The SSD in question is internally connected by SATA, right? If no: How, and is there any other disk anywhere?

Comment: The Samsung T7 Touch is connected via USB… no internal disk present.

Comment: OK, that may the the problem? Can you install it internally?  On the other hand, it may work:  https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=148166 .

Comment: The strange thing is I was able to install same version of Debian on Samsung 860 EVO connected to ThinkPad X1 Yoga Gen 3 using StarTech USB312SAT3CB adapter.

Comment: Feels like I hit one of these strange edge cases…

Comment: Is drive gpt partitioned? It may have seen old MBR partitioning and your exFAT and thought Windows was there, even though Windows cannot be on an external drive. I find with Ubuntu I always have to set label to gpt and add a FAT32 ESP partition before install to any external or second drive. Not sure with Debian.

Comment: Thanks for helping out @oldfred. Disk uses GUID Partition Map so, yes, GPT I believe.

Comment: Have you tried adding the FAT32 EFI partition and perhaps a new ext4 partition for `/` on your Mac?

Comment: I tried using an internal SATA disk and installation completed… I believe issue is an edge case with Samsung T7 Touch. Thanks so much for helping out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up switching to an internal SATA 6 disk and installation completed… guess it was an edge case related to using Samsung T7 Touch.

Comment: I am happy it worked now.

Answer (score 1):

Try "zapping" your disk (unless there is still data you need). Then perhaps the false detection of a possible CSM OS is removed. You cannot use exFAT for Linux, anyway.

This is how:   `// NB this removes all data on your SSD`

Open a root shell. You can do this either in the installer (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>; go back later with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> if you wish) or in a rescue system if the installer offers it.

In the root shell, try to find the hard disk device (likely `/dev/sda`):

```
# lsblk -fm
```

This command will show the installer disk and your SSD. Check carefully which one is which, e.g. by the size or name/label.

I am assuming here that you have found your SSD to be `/dev/sda`.

Zap the disk:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero bs=2M count=5 of=/dev/sda
```

This will essentially overwrite the first 10MB of your disk with zeros, destroying the partition table.

Reboot into the installer, e.g. by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> key combination.

Then tell us whether the installer still detects a possible CSM system.

Comment: I ran `sudo dd bs=1m count=10 if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk4`on macOS to zap disk and, unfortunately, same issue.

Comment: Do you still have the failed partitioning error (your red error screen)?

Comment: Yes, thanks again for helping out btw.